# MySQL problem to find % of house vs % of units

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have below *properties* table;

[image]

I am trying to write a query to pick % of house listed vs % of units listed, broken down by suburb. Rounding of % to be done. Result should be looking something like

| suburb | houses_percent | units_percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vinespark | 100 | 0 |
| burswick | 66.66 | 33.33 |
| rockdale | 33.33 | 66.66 |

I have tried many code alterations but could not get it done.

Comment: I've removed the jquery tag, this question has no relevance to jQuery

Comment: 1) please define how those percentages are supposed to be calculated 2) share what you have tried.

Comment: Houses percentage would be number of of houses in a suburb divided by total (house+units in that suburb)*100.                                                                            
Units percentage would be number of units in a suburb divided by total (house+units in that suburb)*100                                                                                                            This will have to be grouped/listed by each suburb

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the total of houses and units in each suburb.

```
select count(\*) as total 
from Table1
group by suburb;
```

And then use the result as a subquery when finding the number of houses or units in each suburb.

This may get you some of the way:

```
select suburb, type, count(\*)/
(select count(\*) as total 
 from Table1 as T1 
 where Table1.suburb = T1.suburb 
 group by suburb)
as "%"
from Table1 
group by type, suburb;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is count(/*) mean ? Can this be used in mySQL ? Sorry I am new to SQL

Comment: There was some problems with formatting the code. So the slash-star should only have been a star. count(star) mean count all

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

SELECT suburb,
ROUND((100xCOUNT(CASE WHEN type="house" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))/count(type)) AS houses_percent,
ROUND((100xCOUNT(CASE WHEN type="unit" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))/count(type)) AS units_percent
FROM properties
GROUP BY suburb
ORDER BY suburb

Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 0):

By using **Case When**

```
    Select suburb, 
    round(100*count(case when type = "House" Then 1 else null end)/Count(Type)), 
    round(100*count(case when type = "Unit" Then 1 else null end)/Count(Type)) 
    from sales 
    group by suburb
    order by suburb;
```